# Load multipolygons from GeoJSON into GeoDjango model

Tags: geojson, geodjango, geos

I have a simple model:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class CountryShapes(models.Model):
    geonameid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

and a GeoJSON file from here: 
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/shapes_simplified_low.json.zip

I am attempting to load the data into my model using this:

```py
        import json
        from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

        with open('shapes_simplified_low.json', 'r') as fd:
            data = json.load(fd)
            for feature in data['features']:

                geom = GEOSGeometry(str(feature['geometry']))
                geonameid = feature['properties']['geoNameId']

                country = CountryShapes( # throws error here
                    geonameid=geonameid,
                    geom=GEOSGeometry(geom))
                country.save()
```

and I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set CountryShapes SpatialProxy (MULTIPOLYGON) with
>   value of type: class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon'

`GEOSGeometry` seems to create the geometry fine, its when I pass the `geom` argument to my model it throws the error.

Answer (score 6):

The issue: You're trying to save a feature of type 'Polygon' to a field defined for MultiPolygons. (You'll notice a list of geojson features often have both Polygons and MultiPolygons.)

I'm using this hack: If a feature is type Polygon, change it to type MultiPolygon by changing type and putting the coordinates within an array.

```
    geom = GEOSGeometry(str(feature['geometry']))
    if geom.type == 'Polygon':
      geom['type'] = 'MultiPolygon'
      geom['coordinates'] = [feature['geometry']['coordinates']]

    geonameid = feature['properties']['geoNameId']

    country = CountryShapes( # throws error here
        geonameid=geonameid,
        geom=GEOSGeometry(geom))
    country.save()
```

PS: I have almost no experience in Python.

Comment: I put this project on hold for now but will revisit it at some point and let you know if this works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you could also create a Multipolygon directly no? E.g. `feature.geom = MultiPolygon(feature.geom)`

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because the geometry type in the json file is of type **"Polygon"** and the Django geometry field is MultiPolygon. So we have to create a Polygon GEOSGeometry and promote it to a GEOS MultiPolygon. See snippet below.

I have omitted inserting the "geonameid" from the json into the model because it is a primary key. If you want to keep geonameid it would probably be best to have geonameid as a new field and let django handle the primary key.

I also threw a try-except in there to handle the possibility of other geometry types and allow all of the acceptable geometries to be processed.

```
import json
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, Polygon, MultiPolygon

from appname.models import CountryShapes

with open('shapes_simplified_low.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for ft in data['features']:
    geom_str = json.dumps(ft['geometry'])
    geom = GEOSGeometry(geom_str)
    try:
        if isinstance(geom, MultiPolygon):
            continue
        elif isinstance(geom, Polygon):
            geom = MultiPolygon([geom])
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                '{} not acceptable for this model'.format(geom.geom_type)
            )
        
        country = CountryShapes(geom=geom)
        country.save()
        
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```